# How to Download file from Sharepoint to local drive using VBA in an Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, file, sharepoint, download

I'm trying to download a sharepoint file using VBA in an Excel macro.  I copied some code from this site but it will not work.  It downloads a file but the file will not open properly. The correct file is 28KB but the file it downloads is only 4KB.  When trying to open it gives an error message saying the file format or extension is not valid.  Verify the file is not corrupted.  The file downloads and opens with no problem manually but the code does not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://sandvik.sharepoint.com/team/PUMebaneDataHub/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Allitems.aspx

Above is the URL where the file is located. The file is:
Mebane Incident Intake Form.xlsx

here is the actual copied link from Sharepoint
https://sandvik.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/teams/PUMebaneDataHub/Shared%20Documents/Mebane%20Incident%20Intake%20Form.xlsx?d=w8031d09838fe4673854fa5241b259fca&csf=1&web=1&e=ty1IRb

Here is my VBA Code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
    "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _ 
    ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _ 
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _ 
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long 

Sub DownloadFileFromWeb()
    Dim i As Integer
    Const strUrl As String = "https://sandvik.sharepoint.com/teams/PUMebaneDataHub/Shared%20Documents/Mebane Incident Intake Form.xlsx"
    Dim strSavePath As String 
    Dim returnValue As Long 
    strSavePath = "C:\temp1\Mebane Incident Intake Form.xlsx"
    returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strUrl, strSavePath, 0, 0) 
End Sub
```

see above... i was expecting it to download the file .....but it downloads a garbage file that will not open.

Comment: Your "garbage file" is likely some HTML telling you there's a problem with your request.

Comment: Change the file extension on your garbage file to .HTML and then try to open it with a browser.

Comment: Welcome Timothy! Read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: I am trying to download an Excel file.... .not an HTML file.  Please only post useful comments.  My original code was fine.  Apparently this was a bug in Microsoft.  I received an email from Microsoft the next morning.  They asked me to try a few things of which did not matter.  I tried the original code the next day and it worked fine and has been working fine ever since.  The code was not the issue.  A Microsoft bug was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(UrlToWorkbook)
wb.SaveAs savePathHere
```

If you have problems opening the file try removing the `?` and everything following that from the URL.

See https://sharepointcass.com/2021/03/11/what-do-the-parameters-in-a-shared-sharepoint-onedrive-link-mean/ for what those odd parts of the URL (eg) `/:x:` etc actually mean.