VBA Code to Download File from Sharepoint
I would like to use an Excel VBA macro to download a Sharepoint file to local c:\temp1.  I've tried 2 different codes.  One worked for a while but is not consistent.  95% of the time it downloads a file that says is corrupt when trying to open.
Sub DownloadFileFromWeb()
    Dim i As Integer
    Const strUrl As String = "https://sandvik.sharepoint.com/teams/PUMebaneDataHub/Shared%20Documents/Mebane Incident Intake Form.xlsx"
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim returnValue As Long
    strSavePath = "C:\temp1\Mebane Incident Intake Form.xlsx"
    returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strUrl, strSavePath, 0, 0)
End Sub

The code above worked a few times but mostly downloads a corrupt file that will not open.
The code below gives a Run Time error Access is denied.  Not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sub DownloadFileFromSharePoint()
    Dim url As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim xhr As Object
   
    ' SharePoint URL of the file
    url = "https://sandvik.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/teams/PUMebaneDataHub/Shared%20Documents/Mebane%20Incident%20Intake%20Form.xlsx?d=w8031d09838fe4673854fa5241b259fca&csf=1&web=1&e=V88dcS"
    'url = "https://m365x40844952.sharepoint.com/sites/test0108/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test0108/Shared Documents/2.xlsx')/$value"
   'url = "https://sandvik.sharepoint.com/teams/PUMebaneDataHub/Shared%20Documents/Mebane%20Incident%20Intake%20Form.xlsx"
   
    ' Local path to save the file
    savePath = "C:\temp1\Test.xlsx"
   
    ' Create a new XMLHTTPRequest object
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   
    ' Open a connection to the SharePoint file
    xhr.Open "GET", url, False
   
    ' Set authentication headers if necessary (e.g., for SharePoint Online)
    'xhr.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & GetAccessToken()
     
    ' Send the request
    xhr.Send
   
    ' Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    If xhr.Status = 200 Then
        ' Save the file to the local directory
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open
            .Type = 1 ' Binary
            .Write xhr.responseBody
            .SaveToFile savePath, 2 ' Overwrite
            .Close
        End With
        MsgBox "File downloaded successfully."
    Else
        MsgBox "Error downloading file. Status code: " & xhr.Status
    End If
End Sub

see details above*****

This total relates to your company/organization policies: for some, opening the link before downloading resolves the permissions and then you can download it with the code, even in the same company for some colleagues this may or may not work, I haven't found a proper API resolve method for this.

If its an Excel file you can open it directly in Excel and then save it wherever you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043974/478884
